# FIWARE: NGSI-compatible sensors for IoT data gathering

Tags: sensors

I am preparing to conduct a research for `IoT`, collecting environmental data from different sources (temperature, humidity, light, air quality, GPS, etc...). What could the best set of tools or combination that would be most appropriate, especially that `fiware` uses `NGSI` standards.

I come across [uThing::VOC](https://www.hackster.io/ohmtech-io/products/uthing-voc?ref=project-9fa887) USB dongle by Bosch Sensortec but I am not sure if the device is appropriate for data collection unto `fiware` backend such as the kind of experiments described [here](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/iot-sensors/) and [here](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/historic-context/index.html).

How can you advise?

Comment: Please read https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask before asking a question.

Comment: @super_ask , As you may know, the manual for the device is at https://d3s5r33r268y59.cloudfront.net/datasheets/15938/2019-02-09-15-42-47/uThingVOC_datasheet.pdf   You already have the links to the FIWARE documentation. Do you have a specific question ? Read the manuals first if you havent and then ask a specific question about how to do a particular thing or describe a proposed approach and ask if there are any pitfalls in that approach.  If you dont do anything, in a few days, this question will be marked closed.